# Why does the delete/update block each other in this case?

Tags: mysql, locking, transaction, concurrency

The following drives me crazy.
I have:

```
session1>begin;  
session2>begin;  
session2>update dummy set salary=1000 where id=11;  
session1>delete from dummy where id=1;
```

id is the PK of the table.
These statements execute without blocking each other. Makes sense since they refer to different rows.
Next:

```
session1>begin;  
session2>begin;  
session2>update dummy set salary=1000 where id=11;  
session1>delete from dummy where id in (1,2);
```

These also execute without blocking.

```
session1>begin;  
session2>begin;  
session2>update dummy set salary=1000 where id=11;  
session1>delete from dummy where id in (1,2,3,4);
```

These block each other but not always! I can not understand this. These refer to different rows why do they block each other?

Answer (score 1):

*<sub>Answer based on comments by [a-horse-with-no-name](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1822/a-horse-with-no-name)</sub>*

You are probably being hit by MySQL's "gap locking" (locking rows that aren't there).

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-locking.html#innodb-gap-locks

  > Gap locking is not needed for statements that lock rows using a unique index to search for a unique row. (This does not include the case that the search condition includes only some columns of a multiple-column unique index; in that case, gap locking does occur.)
- https://www.percona.com/blog/2012/03/27/innodbs-gap-locks/

  > MySQL uses REPEATABLE READ as the default isolation level so it needs to lock the index records and the gaps to avoid phantom reads and to get a consistent Statement based replication. If your application can deal with phantom reads and your binary log is in row format, changing the ISOLATION to READ COMMITTED will help you to avoid all those extra locks.